# how to get variable alert(test) from var test in success ajax

Tags: javascript

```
$.ajax({    
     type: "post",
     dataType:"json",
     url: "json.php",
     success: function(a) {
        var test = a.data[0]['id'];
     }
   });

alert(test); //not working
```

Comment: what exactly value does it alert eg undefined or anything else

Comment: You need to define test as a global variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

The variable `test` is not global defined it won't alert the value.
try this

```
 var test;
 $.ajax({    
   type: "post",
   dataType:"json",
   url: "json.php",
   success: function(a) {
     test = a.data[0]['id'];
   }
 });

 alert(test);
```

Comment: Also it's asynchronous call it may alert `undefined` because java-script will make an ajax call and move to next statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your var `test` is not global, but also `ajax` is asynchronous called , it will alert test to `undefined` even if you used global `variable` as alert will first execute while ajax is waiting from server response ... so used like below

```
function test(a) { alert(a); }
$.ajax({    
     type: "post",
     dataType:"json",
     url: "json.php",
     success: test
   });
```